# Mock nested static Class and method

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a static class and methods, I want to mock a static method that is called from another static method, is that possible with PowerMockito? I would like to have a mock getServices with when() and a return a defined string when getServiceDetail() is called in unit test.

```
public class MyUtil() {
    private static String getServices() {
        return System.getenv("MY_SERVICES");
    }

    private static String getServiceDetail(String serviceName){

        String serviceDetail;

        if(getServices() != null) {
           ...
        }

        return serviceDetail;

    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyUtil.class);
Mockito.when(MyUtil.getServices()).thenReturn("mysql, rabbit");
```

Comment: Are you mocking the `MyUtil` class too, or are you trying to test the `MyUtil` class?

Comment: Also, in your `getServices() != null` check, are you setting `serviceDetail` to `getServices()`?  There are a lot of questions here.  I am unsure what you are testing (which class, method, etc.), what the expected results are, etc.  Can you provide some more details?